# Transactional Replication - Insert after Delete not working

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

We wanted to have a DR setup for our SQL Server databases.

So for testing purpose we went ahead with Transactional Replication.

**Setup**

- Server 1 (SQL Server 2019): Acting as Distributor and Publisher
- Server 2 (SQL Server 2019): Acting as Subscriber
- IP's are used for configuration, not Server Names (explicitly mentioning this point, since I have went through few blogs were the problems and issues are highlighted due to IP)

The system is working as expected, but following behaviours are observed:

**Problem**

- Deleted all records in Server 1
- Due to transactional replication all of the records are deleted in Server 2
- Post delete inserted records in Server 1
- Expected behaviour was Server 2 will have new records, but it did not
- Re-initialize the subscription via Replication Monitor in SSMS
- Then this worked and records are replicated

I wanted to take this same setup to Production, but this behaviour of Insert after Delete is stopping me to proceed ahead.

What the root cause of this issue?

Is there a way to overcome it or this is the natural behaviour?

How to avoid such situations?

Comment: `Post delete inserted records in Server 1` what does this mean exactly?

Comment: We deleted all of the Records first (Server 1), it was reflected in another Server (Subscriber) all of the records were delete. Then we inserted few records in Server 1, but it did not reflected/inserted in Server 2.

Comment: Does just inserting records work?

Comment: Yes, when I Re-initialized the Subsciber, then all of the records were reflected, also I added more records those all reflected

Comment: Did you execute CHECKPOINT after your insert / delete tests? How is your replication configured?

Comment: Nope, I did not executed CHECKPOINT. I simply configured Transactional Replication following Microsoft Docs.

Comment: i'm just thinking maybe you're too fast, and the records will get replicated soon enough.

Comment: I waited for 20 min, since I configured the scheduled replication for 15 min. Post 20 min also I did not see any records. But after re-initialization it worked seamlessly.

Comment: @ShivkumarMallesappa,  What does the replication monitor shows? Did you checked Log and Snapshot Agent status? Try to query using T-SQL the number of pending records to be replicated.

Comment: @Mr.K Let me try to recreate the scenario and check your suggested inputs.

Comment: @Mr.K I got the error details from Replication Monitor, it states: `The row was not found at the Subscriber when applying the replicated DELETE command for Table '[dbo].[D000043]' with Primary Key(s): [LBrCode] = 101, [EffDate] = 2017-09-11 00:00:00.000, [SrNo] = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need features offered by transactional replication that are not offered by Availability Groups, Log Shipping or Database Mirroring, using one of the latter solutions for disaster recovery will yield an environment that is more reliable and simpler to maintain once everything is up an running.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/sql-server-business-continuity-dr?view=sql-server-ver15

Availability Groups are supported in the standard edition of SQL Server from SQL Server 2016.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver16